# How to change the display content in a NavigationDrawer?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fragment

How can I change content to display after selecting an item in a NavigationDrawer?

I mean, for example, I selected LogIn option in NavigationDrawer, and now I want to change the content that is displayed to another in an XML file.

MainActivity (LauncherActivity) Java file:

```
package com.dotapps.sosgram;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateManager;
import net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManager;
import net.hockeyapp.android.LoginManager;



public class LauncherActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navbar);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        LoginManager.register(this, "SECRET", LoginManager.LOGIN_MODE_EMAIL_PASSWORD);
        LoginManager.verifyLogin(this, getIntent());

        checkForUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.launcher, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_login) {
            // Here I want to change the layout
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_signup) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_fastsos) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_exit){

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }



    // HockeyApp
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkForCrashes();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterManagers();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterManagers();
    }

    private void checkForCrashes() {
        CrashManager.register(this);
    }

    private void checkForUpdates() {
        UpdateManager.register(this);
    }

    private void unregisterManagers() {
        UpdateManager.unregister();
    }
}
```

Content:
[Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_-a6i4oQMHfSHZZX2VKWFZYZm8?usp=sharing)   - *(Due to my few rep, I have to share it via Drive)*

Anyone know how to do it?

---

PD: I've tryed with `setContentView(R.layout.login)`but the app crashes

Comment: Use fragment or activity. create a menu drawer and a switch so that on click you will go to the corresponding fragment/activity.

Comment: Thak you @ScottS. I've solved using FragmentManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with fragments. for more check this links :

http://chrisrisner.com/Using-Fragments-with-the-Navigation-Drawer-Activity

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/